# How to toggle status on a rendered Table - React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table as shown below that displays a status whether true or false. Now, I want to toggle the status with an icon. With my code below, when I click the icon, I see the status changing in my console but on the table.

How can I make the status change reflect on the rendered table when user clicks on each icon on a specific row to change status ?

**Index.js**

```
     state = {
             status: false

       }
        changeStatus(item)
        {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
             status: !prevState.status
           }));
           console.log('status' ,this.state.status)
        }

         <table className="table table-borderless">
           <thead>
              <tr>
              <th>item</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody> 
              {this.state.Data.map((item, key) => (
              <tr>
              <td>Samsung</td>
              <td>    
              {this.state.status == "false" ? (
              <Badge className="mb-10 mr-10" color="danger" pill>False</Badge>  
              ) : (
              <Badge className="mb-10 mr-10" color="success" pill>True</Badge>  
             )}
              </td>              
              <td>
              <i onClick={() => this.changeStatus(item)} className="ti-eye"></i></td>    
               </tr>
                )       
              </tbody>

               </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.state.status == "false"
```

this check is incorrect - both `true`/`false` values from `.state` will give you `false` as a result of this check ( that's why you don't see changes in table)

Try to use

```
<td>{this.state.status? (
              <Badge className="mb-10 mr-10" color="danger" pill>False</Badge>  
              ) : (
              <Badge className="mb-10 mr-10" color="success" pill>True</Badge>  
             )}
              </td>
```

Comment: you swapped the "danger" and "success"

Comment: When `this.state.status=true`, this will print `False`. Your condition is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The simplified conditional rendering is,

```
<td>
    <Badge className="mb-10 mr-10" color={this.state.status ? "success" : "danger"} pill>{this.state.status ? "True" : "False"}</Badge>
</td>
```